# problem with multiple links in discord.js

Tags: hyperlink, discord.js

I am working on a bot that is supposed to react to youtube and soundcloud links, but it only reacts to youtube links, and when I only have soundcloud it does not work, but with YT it does

code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS"] })



client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('The bot is ready')
})

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.channel == 'channelID') {
    if(message.content.includes('https://youtube.com/' || 'https://youtu.be/' || 'https://soundcloud.com/')) {
      message.react('⬆️')
      message.react('⬇️')
    }
  }
})

client.login('Token');
```

I would really appreciate some help, I've been looking around for a few hours and found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the same link as you have provided, and if nothing happens, it means discord just doesn't support soundcloud. I mean after sending YT Link it changes to an embed, and idk if it does with soundcloud also

Comment: SC also becomes an emblem when you paste a link so I don't know what is causing it

Comment: Can you console.log() the message and show the result? If it is very long then do console.log(message.content)? And post it here

Comment: the log does not work, nothing is coming up in cmd terminal

Comment: client.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log(message.content)
})

Comment: I did that, still nothing, could it be that I am missing some packages?

Comment: Can't be, it's integrated into discord.js and it is a discord.js package function, It must be something wrong with your code earlier

Comment: Or try changing itens to 32767, it gives full intents

Comment: Ok, when my friend runs his code it works but when I run the exact same code it says 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS', I don't know what's the problem. I post the updated code that worked for him

Comment: Client missing intents means you or didn't turn it on in discord developer portal, or you didn't do 32767 intents

Comment: When I use, 32767 it says 'DISALLOWED_INTENTS' and I've tries different settings in the "Bot" tab of settings

Comment: In bot tab, turn on public bot, turn off require oauth2 code grant, turn on presence intent, server members intent, and message content intent

Comment: If you could mark my answer as a good one, I would be thankful :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('The bot is ready')
})

client.on('message', (message) => {
  console.log(message.author +" " + message.content)
  if (message.channel == '947192553839669262') {
    if(message.content.startsWith('https://')){
      message.react('⬆️')
      message.react('⬇️')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not good. You should provide an explanation

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).